# Error: Cannot find module 'jquery' on node.js on Heroku

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, heroku

I am trying to include jquery and jsdom to my node.js server hosted on Heroku so that I can make ajax calls using jQuery from the console (not from a web page) like $.ajax({...}).

I keep getting the following error when deploying my Node server on Heroku:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'jquery'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:19:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
Process exited with status 1
```

Here is how my package.json look like:

```
{
  "name": "node-api",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "1.17.1",
    "express": "4.15.2",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jsdom": "10.1.0",
    "mongoose": "4.9.9"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.10.3"
  }
}
```

Here is how I include jquery in server.js:

```
global.jquery = require('jquery');
window.$ = window.jquery = jquery;
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thx,

JS

Answer (score 0):

it seems that heroku is not installing the new packages

you can try set the heroku flag for npm cache to false to force a new fetch of the packages  and deploy again

```
heroku config:set NODEMODULESCACHE=false
git commit -am 'build' --allow-empty 
git push heroku master
heroku config:unset NODEMODULESCACHE
```

Comment: no it doesn't work on my local machine neither. I ended up finding a "jQuery ajax-stye http requests in node" called najax. I am trying it now and it seems to work great! I hope this can help some other folks out there

Answer (score 0):

You can use [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) or a similar package. Example code from their readme file:

```
// json 

fetch('https://api.github.com/users/github')
    .then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
    }).then(function(json) {
        console.log(json);
    });

// catching network error 
// 3xx-5xx responses are NOT network errors, and should be handled in then() 
// you only need one catch() at the end of your promise chain
```

Comment: I tried fetch but I kept running in some issues when handling errors (eg. nhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection). So I tried some other ways to get jQuery working and I finally found a "jQuery ajax-stye http requests in node" called najax. I am trying it now and it seems to work great! I hope this can help some other folks out there

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [najax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/najax) which defines itself as a "jQuery ajax-stye http requests in node".

It works both on my local machine and on heroku.

I hope it can help some other folks out there.